# Parsing through table jQuery provides initial values rather than current one

Tags: jquery, json

I have a very simple table structure

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
  <th>Content</th>
  <th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="content"><input type="text" value="my initial value"></td>
  <td class="option">
  <select>
    <option value="value1" >Value#1</option>
    <option value="value2" >Value#2</option>
    <option value="value3" >Value#3</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
...
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:doIt()" value="do it";>
```

Which I parse in order to create a JSON on submit respective with `chgContentToValue` to write one of the values into the input field.

```
function doIt() {
  var i = 0;
  var json = {};
  $("#mytable tr").each(function () {
    var content = $(this).find(".content").html();
    var option = $(this).find(".option").html();

    if (content != undefined) {
      content = $(content).val();
      option = $(option).val();

      var line = {};
      line['content'] = content;
      line['option'] = option;
      json[i] = line;
      i++;
    }
  });
  json = JSON.stringify(json);
  alert(json);
}
```

Execution:

- open HTML
- change value of input field and/or a different value in the selection
- hit button

I always end up with the initial values instead of the ones that have been changed/keyed in by the user. **Please indicate what my mistake is respective how I can grab the latest values of the input fields & selections.** Many thanks!

Comment: When do you call the upper JS-Code. If you just call it once and not again after the user did some input, thats the reason

Comment: tkx zeropublix, but I can key in into the input fields something and trigger the method which contains the above JS multiple times even minutes later. each & every time the initial values are used instead of the new ones.

Comment: You'd have to prived more code to see further into it since `height = $(height).val()` does not really make sense

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so we can see how this code gets called. Main issue is that you are getting the html of the elements not the value ... an `<input>` has no `html()`

Comment: done, I was attempting to keep it short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the html will always return the element as it was rendered rather than as it is now. Try this instead.

```
$("#mytable tr").each(function () {
var content = $(this).find(".content input");
var option = $(this).find(".option select");

if (content.length > 0) {
  content = content.val();
  option = option.val();

  var line = {};
  line['content'] = content;
  line['option'] = option;
  json[i] = line;
  i++;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing weird things with `html()` on form control elements when all you need is `value`

Try

```
$("#mytable tr").each(function (i) {
  // get value not html
  var content = $(this).find(".content").val();
  var option = $(this).find(".option").val();

  if (content ) {    
    var line = {
       content: content,
       option : option
     };    
    json[i] = line;
    // i++; not needed because index is already available in `each`
  }
});
json = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Comment: many thanks, but this does not work. I am using the weird `html()` in order to first get the td value and later use `val()` on the input field respective selection.